# Wordpress - Single Post full size images

Tags: image, wordpress, post

I'm looking for a way to have ALL of my single post pages (single.php) show the full size image regardless of the custom sizes i've posted for my home index page.

Amongst my many tries and fails i attempted this featured image solution but it didn't really work for my purposes.
http://voodoopress.com/2011/04/woking-with-featured-image-in-wordpress/

Is there a plugin for this that maybe I don't know about?

My PHP knowledge is limited to say the least.
Is there a php code that i can put into the single.php file to make this happen?

Any help is greatly appreciated .
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass a size parameter of 'full' to the the_post_thumbnail() function like this

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>`

Comment: thanks a lot aaron :) I've been looking all over the internet